# Bulk upload users to Azure B2C with custom attributes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to migrate existing users to Azure B2C, I've added a new custom attribute to B2C called "CompanyId". When doing a bulk upload I have added a column to the CSV file called "CompanyId" but the B2C upload facility rejects the file, telling me that the "CompanyId" column header is not valid.

Is it possible to bulk upload users to B2C with custom attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cant bulk upload users with custom attribute on Azure portal using CSV directly. But you can update users' custom attribute after users created using PowerShell as below :

```
Connect-AzureAD  //connect to your b2c tenant

$userNameList = <string array list of signin name of users in your CSV>
$ExtensionName = <extension name of your company id attribute>
$ExtensionValue = <value of your companyID>


$userlist = Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$userNameList.Contains($_.SignInNames[0].Value) }

foreach( $user in $userlist){
   Set-AzureADUserExtension -ExtensionName $ExtensionName -ExtensionValue $ExtensionValue -ObjectId $user.ObjectId
}
```

As you can see, there is one param that we not know is "ExtensionName" . Once we created a custom attribute in B2C, the backend will create an key for it([more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions)), generally the key format is : `extension_<some id>_<name of custom attribute>`. The key is the value of ExtensionName here. To find the key , run the ps command below :

```
Get-AzureADExtensionProperty
```

[image]

I created a custom attribute as you and As you can see, the key in my case is **extension_48c33b45c4f8419eb9d97a0f3ff1817b_CompanyId**

So we can just add this extension key with the value you need to new created users will meet your requirement.

In this case , I uploaded a test user from Azure portal, as you can see, while I use the user to get access token , there is no companyID claim : 
[image]

After run script below :

```
Connect-AzureAD


$userNameList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
$userNameList.Add("newuser")


$ExtensionName = "extension_48c33b45c4f8419eb9d97a0f3ff1817b_CompanyId"
$ExtensionValue = "MSFT"


$userlist = Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$userNameList.Contains($_.SignInNames[0].Value) }

foreach( $user in $userlist){
   Set-AzureADUserExtension -ExtensionName $ExtensionName -ExtensionValue $ExtensionValue -ObjectId $user.ObjectId
}
```

Get an access token by this new created user named "newuser" again : 
[image]
As you can see , the company ID has been set. Hope it helps .